# Are the tiles in our user profile supposed to change color when we unlock them?

Tags: bug, windows-8-challenge

As you can see here, I have completed the second tile by accepting an answer to one of my questions. However, there is no indication of this accomplishment unless I physically mouse-over the tile and look at the text to the right:

[image]

I'm *guessing* this is a [bug](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/bug) since one would expect the tiles to turn blue or something when completed. If this is *not* a bug, then I humbly propose it as a [feature-request](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/feature-request).

---

**Edit:** this must be a bug. [The actual sprite used in the CSS](http://cdn.prom.sstatic.net/MissionPromo/Windows8/img/sprite-tiles.png?v=2) contains two rows of images - one light grey (as pictured above) and one blue.

---

**Edit:** I am using Firefox 16.0.2 on Windows 8 CP 64-bit.

Comment: Yes, they light up. Please include the browser version which makes debugging easier.

Comment: @TomWijsman: Sorry, I stepped away for a few minutes there. I've added the requested info.

Comment: I'm seeing this as well. Same browser & version & OS.

Comment: I can confirm this does not work in Opera 12.02 x64 (Win7 x64), Firefox 16.0.1 (Win7 x64 and x86). However IE9 shows the completed tiles.

Comment: Confirm it doesn't work in Firefox 16.0.2 (Win7 x86 and x64), works in IE 9 though. I'm disappointed that a more cross-browser compatible script wasn't used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this is a bug in your case.  This is what it should look like (using Chrome Version 22.0.1229.94 m):

[image]

Comment: I can confirm that it's working in Chrome.

Comment: @GeorgeEdison Then your problem is that you're using firefox :P